# Cannot load second form c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, forms

I'm working web form. I want to open  a windows form in web page. But cannot load windows form. Can I do it.

```
 protected void btn_insertPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_tagetStartDate.Text != "" &&  txt_targetEndDate.Text != "")
        {
            slmSlct = new SalemanSelect();
            slmSlct.Show();
            btn_insertPerson.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the proper usage is

```
slmSlct.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks you.It loaded.

Comment: sure thing! happy to help